# Having trouble with filestack/angular when upgrading from Angular 12 to 14

Tags: angular, typescript, filestack

I've been attempting to upgrade an application from 12 to 14 and have been having constant issues with filestack/angular. Here are a few examples of the errors that I'm receiving:

```
Error: node_modules/@filestack/angular/projects/filestack-angular/src/lib/filestack-transform.pipe.ts:14:51 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'TransformOptions | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransformOptions'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'TransformOptions'.

14     return this.filestackService.transform(value, transformOptions);
                                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@filestack/angular/projects/filestack-angular/src/lib/filestack.service.ts:25:11 - error TS2564: Property 'clientInstance' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

25   private clientInstance: Client;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@filestack/angular/projects/filestack-angular/src/lib/filestack.service.ts:27:11 - error TS2564: Property 'clientOptions' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

27   private clientOptions: ClientOptions;
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Error: node_modules/@filestack/angular/projects/filestack-angular/src/lib/filestack.service.ts:29:11 - error TS2564: Property 'apikey' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.     

29   private apikey: string;
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@filestack/angular), you need to import filestack like so:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FilestackModule } from '@filestack/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FilestackModule.forRoot({ apikey: YOUR_APIKEY, options: ClientConfig })
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

However I can't even get it to be recognized when I try importing it like that. The only way I've been able to get it to be recognized is by changing the import statement to:

```
import { FilestackModule } from '@filestack/angular/projects/filestack-angular/src/lib/filestack.module';
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: try changing tsconfig.json -> compilerOptions -> strict to false